# upload youtube video using v3 with static user name and password

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api, google-authentication, google-client-login

I am working on app  which require to upload youtube video with static username and password to specfic youtube account channel.I found clientLogin service in v2 which  take static username and password. But ,V2 api are deprecated now.
     Is there any way to upload youtube video using youtube v3 api with static username and password to specific channel?

Comment: Read the documentation. You can't do this anymore. Login that user first.

Answer (score 0):

Client login which was discontinued / shutdown on [April 20 2015](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#timetable). You can no longer use client login with the YouTube API, you need to switch to Oauth2.

BTW this has nothing to do with the fact that its V3 or V2 Google shut down the option for you to login using a login and password.  Its the authentication end point that's discontinued.  None of the Google APIs work anymore with login and password.

Comment: Is there any alternative in new api v3 to upload video to single specific YouTube account channel  as I can not share my account credentials to every user ?

Comment: Depends upon the language you are using.  But you could in theory authenticate your application once safe the authentication then use that to allow others to upload to your channel.  IMO this is probably against Google's terms of service some how.  You cant allow others to impersonate you.